# How to silence or redirect STDOUT when calling external programs?

Tags: julia

Following [docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/) I do:

```
julia> run(`echo hello`)
hello
```

But I actually don't need that output

```
julia> run(`echo hello`)
```

How to turn it off? What am I missing?

---

Inside [process.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/process.jl)
there is a Type called *Process* but I failed to figured how to *spawn* it for now..

Some more insights [here](http://julialang.org/blog/2013/04/put-this-in-your-pipe/)  like

```
julia> x = readall(`echo test`);

julia> x
"test\n"
```

Answer (score 5):

In julia-0.4 one can use:

```
run(pipe(`echo test`, stdout="/dev/null", stderr="/dev/null"))
```

or even more cross-platform

```
run(pipe(`echo test`, stdout=DevNull, stderr=DevNull))
```

NB *pipe* is not defined in julia-0.3